# How to get mail references of bounced mails

Tags: php, email

My PHP app allows users to invite members by e-mail. I want to inform the inviting user if there was a problem with the invitation, for this case when I got a back Non-Delivery Report.

Before sending the mail with PHP mailer I am defining the messageID like this:

```
$mail->MessageID = unique@domain.com
```

This custom setted ID gets also written in the database. This works fine.

Next I am observing the mailbox from which the mails were sent with the following script for test purposes:

```
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.example.org:143}INBOX", "username", "password")
or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

$MC = imap_check($mbox);

// Fetch an overview for all messages in INBOX
$result = imap_fetch_overview($mbox,"1:{$MC->Nmsgs}",0);
foreach ($result as $overview) {
    echo "#{$overview->msgno} ({$overview->references}) - From: {$overview->from}
    {$overview->subject}\n";
}
imap_close($mbox);
```

When answering a email by hand this script perfectly gives back the before set message id as reference. So if this reference fits to a message id in the database I am able to inform the user that someone replied to their mail.

However when there comes back a bounce mail the references property is empty. Is there a straight forward to get the message id of the initial mail?

Setting up a different reply-to address is no option because I want to send an user friendly notification with some troubleshoot information

Comment: Maybe you can compare the `Message-ID` header from [rfc822](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_3_Message.html) with the one from the bounce mail?

Comment: There is a mechanism called VERP which is used for tracking bounces. There is no sane way to track what bounced because email server vendors *(cough* Microsoft *cough* flee from Mordor *cough)* don't always do a good job of indicating what exactly happened when they send a bounce.